# How to write a Map for a list of objects using Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of user objects called `allUsers` and I need to check each object in it with the `groupId` which is passed to the function and return `userNames` which have the passed `groupId`.

I attempted this in the following manner.

```
vm.setNames=function(groupId){
        var products = "";
        angular.forEach(vm.allUsers,function (f) {
            if(f.groupId==groupId){
                vm.user=f;
                users= users+','+" "+vm.user.userName;
            }
        })

        return users= ;
    }
```

I want to have it in a map with group id as the key and relevant user names as values and return the relevant user names. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve that using the `Array.reduce` prototype function:

```
var allUsers = [
  { groupId: 1, userName: 'mario' },
  { groupId: 1, userName: 'luigi' },
  { groupId: 2, userName: 'peach' },
  { groupId: 2, userName: 'koopa' }
]

var getNames = function getNames(groupId, users) {
  return users.reduce(function(res, u) {
    if (u.groupId === groupId) {
      res = res + (res.length > 0 ? ', ' : '') + u.userName
    }
    return res
  }, '')
}

console.log(getNames(1, allUsers))
```